# How to "really" down-cast a DynamicProxy back to its original type (to send over WCF)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

OK, the situation is we have a class, `PatientDto`, and a DynamicProxy generated by Castle, `PatientDtoProxy`.

We're using this proxy in the Silverlight client, then want to send it back to the server via a WCF service call.

The WCF service Contract expects a `PatientDto` (ie not the proxy) and, as expected, blows up if you try to send anything else.

Essentially, we feel like we should be "casting" it back to a `PatientDto` to get things to work... but in reality, even if you cast the reference down to PatientDto, it doesn't change anything -- WCF still sees the object in memory as a `PatientDtoProxy` and blows up.

Obviously, doing a deep-copy into a new'ed up `PatientDto` is an option (and does work), but an unpleasant one.  Any techniques we're just not thinking of?

Comment: Is it an interface based proxy or a class-based one?  If the latter, doesn't your proxy instance already inherit from PatientDto?

Comment: class-based, and yep you're right it does - WCF still complains.  I assume it's using reflection on the object itself, and sees that it's really a 'PatientDtoProxy'.. even though we've casted the -reference' to the base type...  that's the dilemma

Comment: Yeah, tricky.  Ideally, you would set the KnownTypes attribute on the base class to include the subclass.  Obviously this is not possible with a dynamically created proxy. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using AutoMapper and mapping your proxy to a real PatientDto object. Or just manually mapping it yourself.

Comment: sounds like the fallback option I mentioned - to do a deep-copy from the Proxy to a new object in memory of the base type.. seems like a suboptimal solution doesn't it?  Some kind in-place cast would be ideal.. just not sure if that's possible

Comment: There's nothing about mapping that is ever optimal.

Comment: just getting back to this - looking back doing a deep copy is probably the only way to go, so you get a check, finally.  thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just to add a more favourable alternative to mapping to a new object, you can just extract the underlying object.

I use a helper class to do this:

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;

namespace Magna.Client.Common.Proxy
{
    public class ProxyDtoUtils
    {
        public static T GetUnderlying<T>(T proxy)
        {
            return ProxyUtil.IsProxy(proxy) ? (T)ProxyUtil.GetUnproxiedInstance(proxy) : proxy;
        }
    }
}
```